# passing arguments to another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I am trying to pass some arguments from a button calling the first function "fadesIn()" to another function "check()" which will keep checking if the first image has faded before fading in the second image. To pass the arguments I tried useing

```
function.apply(this, arguments);
```

then call the required arguments using the array position. Unfortunately I am unable to make it work on my webpage. I'm only just learning so there is probably something I'm missing... Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var time;

function fadesIn(args){
    fadeOut(arguments[1]);
    check.apply(this, arguments);
    check();
} 

function check(args){
    if(document.getElementById(arguments[1]).style.opacity < 0.1){
        fadeIn(arguments[0]);
        clearTimeout(time);
        return;
    }
    time=setTimeout(function(){check()},100);
}   

fadesIn('pic1', 'pic2');
```

geez you guys are quick to respond.. thanks..

this is the fade in and out functions, they are from develop php on youtube

```
var fade_in_from = 0;
var fade_out_from = 10;

function fadeIn(element){
    var target = document.getElementById(element);
    target.style.display = "block";
    var newSetting = fade_in_from / 10;
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;
    // opacity ranges from 0 to 1
    fade_in_from++;

    if(fade_in_from == 10){
        target.style.opacity = 1;
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fade_in_from = 0;
        return false;
    }

    var loopTimer = setTimeout('fadeIn(\''+element+'\')',50);
}

function fadeOut(element){
    var target = document.getElementById(element);
    var newSetting = fade_out_from / 10;
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;
    fade_out_from--;

    if(fade_out_from == 0){
        target.style.opacity = 0;
        target.style.display = "none";
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fade_out_from = 10;
        return false;
    }

    var loopTimer = setTimeout('fadeOut(\''+element+'\')',50);
}
```

I will have a play around with your suggestions.

the error from firebug is

TypeError: document.getElementById(arguments[1]) is null

Comment: Where is `fadeOut` defined? Any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: So `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are functions declared somewhere else? What errors do you get in the console? What exactly does not work in your page?

Answer (score 0):

```
check();
// and
setTimeout(function(){check()},100);
```

seem to cause some problems. Your `check` function expects [at least] two arguments, otherwise `document.getElementById(arguments[1])` will return `null` and accessing the `style` property of that throws an exception.

As you only use two arguments at all, it's better not to use the `arguments` object but just pass the two parameters:

```
function fadesIn(pic1, pic2) {
    fadeOut(pic2);
    check(pic1, pic2);
} 

function check(argOne, argTwo){
    if(document.getElementById(argTwo).style.opacity < 0.1){
        fadeIn(argOne);
        clearTimeout(time);
        return;
    }
    time=setTimeout(function(){check(argOne, argTwo)},100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Bergi you are correct... could I maybe put the values into a global variable from within fadesIn() then query that in the check() function, or is there anything else you would suggest to achieve the same result?

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want to do, but you already have showed us how to pass on the `arguments` successfully - although I'd recommend just 2 named parameters

Comment: this is what I want to do [link](http://jsfiddle.net/synthet1c/7epJw/)js fiddle link. not sure why it doesn't work on JS Fiddle, but in the browser it is fine. I ended up just using a global variable as the holder of the information but will probably end up changing it to an object literal to not pollute the global namespace. Thanks for your help